# How can I render a tr with soy templates?

Tags: html, google-closure-templates, soy-templates

I've got this soy template

```
{template .myRowTemplate}
  <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
{/template}
```

and I want to do something like

```
var myTable = goog.dom.createElement("table");
goog.dom.appendChild(myTable, goog.soy.renderAsFragment(mytemplates.myRowTemplate));
goog.dom.appendChild(myTable, goog.soy.renderAsFragment(mytemplates.myRowTemplate));
```

But that causes

```
Uncaught goog.asserts.AssertionError
Assertion failed: This template starts with a <tr>,
which cannot be a child of a <div>, as required by soy internals. 
Consider using goog.soy.renderElement instead.
Template output: <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Why it fails

Right, the documentation of `renderAsFragment` is a bit confusing; it reads:

> Renders a Soy template into a single node or a document fragment. If the rendered HTML string represents a single node, then that node is returned

However, the (simplified) implementation of `renderAsFragment` is:

```
  var output = template(opt_templateData);
  var html = goog.soy.ensureTemplateOutputHtml_(output);
  goog.soy.assertFirstTagValid_(html); // This is your failure
  var safeHtml = output.toSafeHtml();
  return dom.safeHtmlToNode(safeHtml);
```

So why do the closure author assert that the first tag is not `<tr>`?

That's because, internally, `safeHtmlToNode` places `safeHtml` in a temporary `div`, before deciding if it should return the `div` wrappper (general case) or the only child (if the rendered HTML represents only one Node). Once again simplified, the code of `safeHtmlToNode` is:

```
  var tempDiv = goog.dom.createElement_(doc, goog.dom.TagName.DIV);
  goog.dom.safe.setInnerHtml(tempDiv, html);
  if (tempDiv.childNodes.length == 1) {
    return tempDiv.removeChild(tempDiv.firstChild);
  } else {
    var fragment = doc.createDocumentFragment();
    while (tempDiv.firstChild) {
      fragment.appendChild(tempDiv.firstChild);
    }
    return fragment;
  }
```

## renderAsElement won't work either

And I'm unsure what you are asking for fragments, but unfortunately `goog.soy.renderAsElement()` will behave the same because it also uses a temporary `div` to render the DOM.

## renderElement cannot loop

The error message suggests `goog.soy.renderElement`, but that will only work if your table has one row, since it replaces content, and doesn't append children nodes.

## Recommended approach

So usually, we do the for loop in the template:

```
  {template .myTable}
    <table>
    {foreach $person in $data.persons}
      <tr><td>Hello {$person.name}</td></tr>
    {/foreach}
    </table>
  {/template}
```

Of course, we can keep the simple template you have for one row and `call` it from the larger template.

Comment: Use $Person in place of Person in the recommended approach.